# A problem occurred evaluating project > No signature of method: is applicable

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I keep getting this error when I build my Android application.

Seems to be specifically linked with [@shopify\react-native-skia](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/getting-started/installation) package.

```
Build file 'D:\dev\proton\node_modules\@shopify\react-native-skia\android\build.gradle' line: 127

A problem occurred evaluating project ':shopify_react-native-skia'.
> No signature of method: build_dv9glgdfsyi4kws5so83p71u2.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_dv9glgdfsyi4kws5so83p71u2$_run_closure2) values: [build_dv9glgdfsyi4kws5so83p71u2$_run_closure2@46d7e7d8]

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have double checked npm and the package is installed fine.

Here is the snippet of code that the error is pointing to (build.gradle):

```
android {
    def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
    if (agpVersion.tokenize('.')[0].toInteger() >= 7) {
      namespace "com.shopify.reactnative.skia"
    }

    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION)
```

Any idea what's going on here?

For context, I'm using RN version 0.72.7